# What happens to a Sine wave in the frequency domain?

Tags: communication, frequency

1. Say for eg.if we have a sinusoidal signal of

f = 1KHZ, VPP = 1V and Voffset = 0V

2. If I change my Offset Voltage from 0v to +5 V, What would be the effects in Time domain and frequency domain?

Comment: what do you mean "happens"? time domain is just a way to display things, it doesnt change the signal, its just another way to look at it. if you change the amplitude, it will look like a signal with a different amplitude...

Comment: Time domain: shifts the sinusoid up by 5V. Frequency domain: adds a component to the spectrum at 0Hz (or 'DC')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will see a single peak at 1KHz. 
In the frequency domain, increasing the offset won't change the peak you see at 1Khz, but will create a new peak at 0 Hz.
In time domain, increasing the offset to 5V will simply change the mean voltage of your sine wave to 5V, it won't change the amplitude of the wave.

The first part of [this](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/22536/what-type-of-information-can-i-get-from-the-waveform-and-the-spectrum-of-audio)  answer will help you.

Comment: Ciao Marazzi, will the single peak at 1 KHz have the same amplitude as Vpp? 

And, in the Frequency domain, increase in offset will result in two peaks ; one at 1KHz and other at 0 Hz, if I am not wrong. Could you please help me with the little more explanation on why we get an additional peak and what would be the amplitude of this new peak at 0Hz? 
Grazie.

Comment: It is more precise to say that, using the amplitude of the peak that you see in the frequency domain, you could get the amplitude of the wave because the two are related but not in a 1:1 relationship

Comment: Regarding the second question, it's a bit long to explain in a comment. It's explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform
"The Fourier transform decomposes a function of time (a signal) into the frequencies that make it up"

Comment: Since you have a wave resulting from the sum of a "0 Hz wave" (the DC offset) and a 1kHz wave (the sine), you will see two peaks at these frequencies.